# Making a FileHandler more OOP-friendly using SOLID

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, file-system

I have a class created for the sole purpose is to help handle files.  The class holds a path (folder) that contains a single file at a time. Some extra properties to this class are: age of a file and max file size. I'm a very procedural style coder, and I'm trying to shift my work to a more OOP and eventually end up with something more SOLID.

The `FileHandler` receive a path and a file name. A majority of the functions described are basically a wrapper for system file manipulation. Now before you wonder why wrap things when you easily call them: I want to OOP this and on a bigger scale files are being manipulated for processing from another object. Another reason why I did this, up until recently `file_get_content()` was nice so far with files under 2MB but as it is growing now using file_get_content is no longer ideal, so on a larger application I will be changing commands.

Small goal:

A worker object process files by writing into files. If we set the max file to be MB, it needs to check for this, and create a new file, switch to it and continue writing into this. It should also check if the file it tries to write into is not idle for more than `MAX_EXPIRE`.

Another (independent) worker process files. It takes a single file, reads it, and moves it.

One of the more important concept that I got stuck on is that now I have this class that works but I need to refactor it into a Code with Intent (so that it follows SOLID).  Is it already there? Can we do more? Should I break it into more classes to serve my purpose?

```
class FileHandler 
{
    protected $path;
    protected $file_name;
    protected $max_file_size;
    protected $max_age;
    protected $creation_time = false;


    public function __construct($file_path = "./", $file_name = '', $size = 5242880, $max_age = 900)
    {
        $this->path = $file_path;
        $this->file_name = $file_name;
        $this->max_file_size = $size;
        $this->max_age = $max_age;
    }

    public function fileExists()
    {
        return @file_exists($this->path.'/'.$this->file_name);
    }

    public function directoryExists()
    {
        return @file_exists($this->path);
    }

    public function read()
    {
        if ($this->isFile($this->path."/".$this->file_name)) {
            return @file_get_contents($this->path."/".$this->file_name);
        }

        throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist at path {$this->path}");
    }

    public function write(DataRepository $data)
    {
        if (!file_put_contents($this->path."/".$this->file_name, $data->getData(), FILE_APPEND)) {
            throw new FileCannotWriteException("Unable to write in the log file : ".$this->file_name);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        if (!$this->directoryExists()) {
            $this->makeDirectory($this->path);
        }
        $this->creation_time = time();
        return file_put_contents($this->path."/".$this->file_name, '');

    }

    public function dataSize()
    {
        return @filesize($this->path."/".$this->file_name);
    }


    public function delete()
    {
        return @unlink($this->path."/".$this->file_name);
    }


    public function changeFile($file_name)
    {
        $this->file_name = $file_name;
    }


    public function changeDirectory($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
        if (!$this->isWritable()) {
            $this->makeDirectory($this->path);
        }
    }


    public function writeLimit()
    {
        clearstatcache();

        return ($this->dataSize()<$this->max_file_size) ? true : false;
    }


    public function isWritable()
    {
        return is_writable($this->path."/".$this->file_name);
    }


    private static function _glob($pattern, $flags = 0)
    {
        return glob($pattern, $flags);
    }



    public static function files($directory)
    {
        $glob = self::_glob($directory.'/*');

        if ($glob === false) {
            return array();
        }

        return array_filter($glob, function ($file) {
            return filetype($file) == 'file';
        });
    }


    public function makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, $recursive = false, $force = false)
    {
        if ($force) {
            return @mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
        } else {
            return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
        }
    }


    public function moveFile($target)
    {
        $file_name = $this->file_name;
        if (@rename($this->path."/".$file_name, $target."/".$file_name)) {
            $this->file_name = "";
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isFile($file)
    {
        return is_file($file);
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function lockFile()
    {
        if ($lock = @fopen($this->path."/".$this->file_name, "r+")) {
            if (@flock($lock, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) {
                return $lock;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function unlockFile($lock)
    {
        if ($lock !== null) {
            if (flock($lock, LOCK_UN)) {
                $lock = null;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getLastModification()
    {
        return filemtime($this->path."/".$this->file_name);
    }

    public function getRelativeFilename()
    {
        return $this->file_name;
    }

    public function getAbsoluteFilename()
    {
        return $this->path."/".$this->file_name;
    }

    public function isMaxAgeReached()
    {
        return $this->creation_time !== false && time() - $this->creation_time >= $this->max_age;
    }

    public static function generateFileFolderByDate($file)
    {
        $timestamp = false;
        $name_type_1 = '#filelog_\d+_(\d+)\.log#';
        $name_type_2 = '#(\d+)_filelog_\d+\.log#';
        if (preg_match($name_type_1, $file, $match) || preg_match($name_type_2, $file, $match)) {
            $timestamp = $match[1];
        }
        if ($timestamp === false) {
            return '';
        }

        return date('Ymd', $timestamp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The class in on itself seems fine to me, but the question you should be asking is **what problem am I solving here?**.

OOP design works well on the big picture. Let's say you have a simple application where you want to CRUD a user's contacts. And let's say that you decided for some reason not to use a database but to use plain 'ol files.

In that case, it makes sense for your application to work with `User` and `Contact` objects, where each `User` object contains a bunch of `Contact` objects.   Have you noticed what the application doesn't know? That's right, **the application has no idea where the data came from**, and that's part of SOLID.

In that sense, you would have `UserMapper` and `ContactMapper` to connect the User and Contact  respectively to the files. Note that even the User or Contact objects don't know where the data they hold came from. Example:

```
class User {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $contacts;
}

class UserMapper implements Mapper {
    public function fetch($id, User $user) {
        //Talk to files to get the information needed for the user, and map that information to the $user object.
        $user->name = $someQueryResult->getName();
        //etc...
    }
    public function save(User $user) {
        //Save user details back to files
    }
}
```

Note that this way the User has no knowledge of where the data in it came from, could have been files, could have been a session or even a REST api.

---

So you see, it's nice to have a FileHandler helper to do some tasks, but it all comes down to how things work together in your general application sense.